# Grammatical analysis of a sentence

Tags: grammar, sentence, subjects, objects

Good afternoon! Please could you help me to define what parts of a sentence are included in this phrase:
"The most interesting thing for me is to create pictures".
What is a subject and what is a predicate here?
Is "thing" an optional element?
Why isn't "for me" situated at the end of the phrase?
Thank you in advance...

Comment: I really think this question would translate into your own language with basically the same order of words. Kindly tell us what you think the subject is. Open-ended questions on basic grammar are not really the type of question we answer here.

Comment: @Lambee I should formulate it better. I have received an answer below. The main question was about a place of "for me", other questions were excessive or maybe additional.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> - *The most interesting thing for me is to create pictures.*

First, this is not a phrase; this is a sentence. Phrases are **parts** of sentences.

Second, like all English sentences, it has a subject noun phrase and a predicate verb phrase.

The subject noun phrase is

- *the most interesting thing for me*

and the predicate verb phrase is

- *is to create pictures*.

Neither of these is a simple phrase; the subject phrase has a superlative construction in it, and the verb phrase is equative, with an infinitive clause equated to the subject.

*For me* is located where it is because it modifies *most interesting*; the speaker is judging interest from their own experience. It could go at the beginning, with a comma, but that would emphasize the personal nature; it really couldn't go anywhere else in the sentence without changing the meaning or creating ungrammaticality.

*Thing,* while essentially meaningless, is nevertheless not optional. It's required because English does not allow adjectives to stand as nouns except in very special cases. If we say *the old* we mean generically old people as a class, but we can't mean 'that old guy over there' the way *el anciano* or *der Alte* might in Spanish or German. *Thing* is the dummy noun that we use as a crutch in such cases (for non-living nouns; for people, *guy, lady, folks, people,* etc. are common).

There's lots more grammar in the sentence; superlatives are very complex, and the infinitive has no subject, for instance. But this is long enough already.

Comment: Thank you very much for such a detailed and interesting answer, @JohnLawler! I should formulate my question more clearly. The sticking point for me was ... a place of "for me"). Now I see that it is not an object but a part of a subject.

Comment: the most interesting thing [for me,for them, for us]. I don't see how those would not be prepositional phrases. They could be left out and the subject would still stand or work....

Comment: Indeed. The experiencer is optional with a flip predicate like _be interesting_; it's assumed to be the speaker (who is a position to judge their interest, anyway) unless otherwise specified. With _interesting_, the experiencer is expressed with a preposition (either _to_ or _for_, no difference, speaker's choice).